# insert json string into mysql

Tags: mysql, json, perl, dbi

I want to store json string in mysql db. 
But seems there is some quotation issue, I can't figure out.

```
use DBI;
use JSON;

#some staff

my $json_string = encode_json \%DB;

#DBI CONNECTION...

# insert data into the links table
my $sql = "INSERT INTO `tech_nodes` (`meta`).
    VALUES(?)";
my $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(1, $json_string );

# execute the query
$stmt->execute();
```

Error:

> DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '.
>           VALUES('{\"techs\":{\"A\":{\"B\":null,\"techs\":{\"stack.tc'
>   at line 1 at ./stacks.pl line 121. DBD::mysql::st execute failed: You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.
>           VALUES('{\"techs\":{\"A\":{\"B\":null,\"techs\":{\"stack.tc'
>   at line 1 at./stacks.pl line 121.

Table description:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tech_nodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `meta` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `generated_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing that period after the closing parenthesis after `meta`.